# Are infinite cyclic normal subgroups "virtually" central?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and let $C$ be an infinite cyclic normal subgroup of $G$. My question is: Does $G$ necessarily have a finite-index subgroup $H$ such that $C \le Z(H)$? If not, then are there well-known assumptions that make it so?

I have an idea for an argument, but I'm afraid I might be misunderstanding some things about subgroup distortion, so I'm asking here in case someone knows the answer for sure.

Comment: Yes, $|{\rm Aut}(C)|=2$, so $|G:C_G(C)| \le 2$. (No need to assume that $G$ is finitely generated.)

Comment: What is $Z(H)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt So simple, thanks!