# When are free abelian normal subgroups "virtually" central?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups, free-abelian-group

See my previous question for the motivation for this question:

[Are infinite cyclic normal subgroups "virtually" central?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846729/are-infinite-cyclic-normal-subgroups-virtually-central?noredirect=1#comment7935337_3846729)

Let $G$ be a (finitely generated) group and let $K \lhd G$ be a normal subgroup such that $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some $n \ge 2$. When does $G$ have a finite-index subgroup $H$ such that $K \le Z(H)$?

The simple argument to answer my previous question won't work since $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^n) = GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is infinite for $n \ge 2$.

**EDIT**: I remembered that I do know of one sufficient condition. Namely, if $K$ is quasi-isometrically embedded in $G$, then such an $H$ does exist.

To try to expand and clarify my question: Are there any (other) well-known assumptions or conditions that are sufficient to guarantee there exists a finite-index subgroup $H \le G$ and a finite-index subgroup $K' \le K$ such that $K' \le Z(H)$?

Comment: I find questions like this difficult to interpret. What kind of answer are you looking for? The condition is equivalent to $|N_G(K):C_G(K)|$ being finite, or to the subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ induced by conjugation in $G$ being finite, but that's almost tautological.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry for any vagueness; I've edited the post now. I had asked the question in case anyone had thought about this before and could give any insights off the top of their head. For example, I was struggling with my previous question and trying to work with things like subgroup distortion, but it turned out to have such an easy answer from a purely (basic) group-theoretic perspective.

Comment: For the last question, trivially $H=K'=K$ works...

Comment: @YCor I would like $H$ to be a finite-index subgroup of $G$, and $K$ may have infinite index?